# vue.js pass argurments in filters with $options

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I am calling the built in `Currency` filter in an application like so

`this.$options.filters.currency(this.meta[i].metadata_value)`

Inside html I can pass arguments to change the decimal points to 0 by doing

```
{{ data | currency 0 }}
```

How can I pass 0 in the options way since I need to call it in a method?

Answer (score 1):

I got it. You pass it like a function but you have to enter a first argument like

`this.$options.filters.currency(this.meta[i].metadata_value, '$', 0)`